# How dependency parse tree is used for sentiment analysis?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, syntaxnet

With the announcement from Google on release of Parsey McParseface [syntaxnet](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/05/announcing-syntaxnet-worlds-most.html)
which is claimed to be the most accurate dependency parser. I want to understand how this parser can be used for more accurate sentiment analysis ? If someone can share some blogs or research papers or tutorials which can help me understand the overall flow.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, Im not expert, in fact I got intrigued when you asked the question.

**td;lr;** more accurate dependency parsers would in allow one propagate sentiment through a graph and thus better determine sentiment polarity, at least in theory.

It seems from my reading that sentiment analysis using dependency tree graphs propagate the independent (prior -- sentiment you might get from a lexicon) sentiment of words to compose overall sentiment polarity of the text.

This approach uses the composition of language (its grammatical structure) to determine sentiment. This is somewhat* opposed to a statistical (naives bayes, logistics regression, neural networks) approach to understanding sentiment.

Here's the paper I scanned:

http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/FLAIRS/FLAIRS14/paper/viewFile/7869/7837

For a deeper exploration of whats possible, this might help:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6330.pdf

A more through introduction to dependency parsing if you're interested might be https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/14.pdf

*somewhat in the sense that (in particular) convolution networks do learn a certain composition of language so do rnns.